# NodeJS: Append file inside a callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, electron, fs

I have a **Electron JS app** that starts a **independent child process (non-blocking)** (binary application) that I wrote in C++.

I would like **to stream** the C++ standard output [STDOUT] to NodeJS and **log it in a log text file.**

I already saw the differences between using `spawn()`, `fork()`, `exec()` and `execFile()` in the NodeJS Child Process documentation [(link here)](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). In my case, I need to use the `spawn()` method.

So here is my Electron JS / NodeJS code:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require("fs");
const cp = require("child_process");

[... another stuffs ...]

// Start a child process:
const child = cp.spawn(my_binary, ["param1", "param2", "param3"], { detached: true });
child.unref();

// STDOUT listener:
child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
child.stdout.on("data", (data) => {

    // Set the log file path:
    let filePath = path.join(__dirname, "..", "logs", logFilename);

    // Try to append: I GOT A REFRESH PAGE LOOP HERE:
    fs.appendFile(filePath, data, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("[STDOUT]", err);
        } else {
            // Get the C++ STDOUT output data:
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
})
```

This code actually **works** and it log the C++ output in a `log_timestamp.txt` file.

### My problem

When I call this NodeJS file, the ElectronJS **web interface and browser console refreshs a lot of times per second in a infinite refresh loop.** So, each time that Electron JS refreshes the page, NodeJS starts again **a new child process.**
Finally, I get a lot of `log_timestamp.txt` **in a few seconds.**

If I remove only the `fs.appendFile()` and replace it by `console.log(data)`, **I got my desired console log output just one time, without page refreshes or anormal behaviors.**
Exemple:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require("fs");
const cp = require("child_process");

[... another stuffs ...]

// Start a child process:
const child = cp.spawn(my_binary, ["param1", "param2", "param3"], { detached: true });
child.unref();

// STDOUT listener:
child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
child.stdout.on("data", (data) => {

    // Set the log file path:
    let filePath = path.join(__dirname, "..", "logs", logFilename);

    // Get the C++ STDOUT output data:
    console.log(data);
})
```

**What m'I doing wrong?**
**How can I fix the first source-code in a way to log correctly the C++ output in a text file?**

**My system is:**

- Electron 7.1.2
- Node 12.13.0
- Windows 10 x64 and Ubuntu 18 x64

### UPDATE 1

Following the @Jonas suggestion, I tried this alternative code, but I got the same anormal behavior yet.

```
// Start a child process:
const child = cp.spawn(bin, ["param1", "param2", "param3"], { detached: true });
child.unref();

// STDOUT listener:
child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
child.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log(data);
})

let filePath = path.join(__dirname, "..", "logs", logFilename);
child.stdout.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath));
```

Answer (score 1):

The point of streams is that you can just pipe them together and let the engine handle all the rest:

```
 child.stdout.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(/*...*/));
```

I assume that your main problem is that `appendFile` has to open the file, lock it, write to it, unlock it, and that happens on every chunk of data. This will slow down writing, and as you don't handle backpressure correctly, memory consumption starts to raise and probably leads to the lag you are seeing.

Comment: Thank you @Jonas Wilms for your quick answer.

I did this change, but I got the same anormal behavior.

Do you have another ideas?

Comment: I'm a newer in a ElectronJS and NodeJS programming...so I don't know how to find/use the profiler?

The anormal thing is that: When I try to append the C++ output to a text file, ElectronJS is refreshing the front-end a lot of times per second. So, each time that it occours, NodeJS starts a new child process and I got a lot of log files.

I want to create a single log file. To do that, my Electron web interface *can't* refresh all the time.

Do you have another sugestion?